# How to avoid KeyError when working with dpath?

Tags: python, dpath

I'm using `dpath` to access nested dictionaries in a much cleaner way.

With `dpath` I can do:

```py
result = dpath.util.get(data, "/data/attributes/policy_revision/policy")
```

Instead of:

```py
result = data.get("data", {}).get("attributes", {}).get("policy_revision", {}).get("policy", "")
```

However, the only problem using `dpath` is that I'm getting a `KeyError` when any of the keys in the path doesn't exist. Whereas using the `get` allows me to specify the default value in case the key is not found.

I could try to capture the `KeyError` exception but that would make code a lot longer and complex, losing the tidiness that `dpath` initially gives me.

My question is, how can I specify the default value in `dpath`?

This is their documentation but I haven't found anything related: https://pypi.org/project/dpath/

Comment: I guess that you have to `try` / `except KeyError` with `dpath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find how they handle default value in their github repo:

https://github.com/dpath-maintainers/dpath-python/blob/master/dpath/util.py

line:148,173~175

code:

```
import dpath.util
x = {
    "a": {
        "b": {
        "3": 2,
        "43": 30,
        "c": [],
        "d": ['red', 'buggy', 'bumpers'],
        }
    }
}
print(dpath.util.get(x, '/a/b/42', default = -1))
print(dpath.util.get(x, '/a/b/43', default = -1))
```

result:

```
-1
30
```

Comment: Awesome find @leaf_yakitori, thank you! I wonder why it is not documented

Comment: @Xar Maybe they forget to document it, you can raise an issue on their github repo to report it.